# Android: how to implement scrolling/moving background floating buttons and textviews

Tags: android

I'm not even sure where to look to do this. I have an already made relative layout with buttons and textviews.

Is it possible to have  top layer that the user can interact ( my relative layout) with  transparent background

Then a bottom layer thats a background image thats scrolling. Thats outside of the control of the user.  For example a scrolling image of space. Thats continually scrolling.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

#### Getting your root layout here it is --> RelativeLayout

#### Create animation file which consists of frame image files or transform | rotate | alpha whatever your animation is

Here the code looks like : Transform it on your needs-

#### animation file :: anim/push_down.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:oneshot=["true" | "false"] >
    <item
    android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource_name"
    android:duration="integer" />
   </animation-list>
```

#### Implementing inside the code

```
   RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutSearch);
   Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_down);
   a=setFillAfter(true); 
   layout.setLayoutAnimation(new LayoutAnimationController(a));
   layout.startLayoutAnimation();
```